# phpmailer don't put in header DKIM informations

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, dkim

I'm working to put DKIM signature in the emails sent with a small crm I've created.
I've insert the public key in the text record of my domain and now I'm working to put private key in phpmailer when I'm sending a email.
I used the example inside the class:

```
$mail->DKIM_domain = 'example.com';
$mail->DKIM_private = 'path/to/private.key';
$mail->DKIM_selector = 'phpmailer';
$mail->DKIM_passphrase = '';
$mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;
```

when I send the mail gmail says my dkim signature is PASS. If i test the mail sending it at check-auth@verifier.port25.com I recieve:

> ---------------------------------------------------------- DKIM check details:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------- Result:         permerror (hash algorithm used in signature (sha256) ID(s) verified:
>   not

Comment: with php mail() https://github.com/breakermind/PHP-DKIM or with phpmailer  https://github.com/breakermind/PHP-DKIM/blob/master/zips/dkim-cron-send.php

Answer (score 0):

Hello did you try https://www.port25.com/authentication-checker/ and paste output when you test it.

Also I had similiar problems and this answer helped me 
[How to send email with Phpmailer with DKIM signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705035/how-to-send-email-with-phpmailer-with-dkim-signature)

You might try it also

Comment: ------------------------------
SPF check details:
------------------------------
Result: pass 
ID(s) verified: smtp.mailfrom=info@hotelbeverlyrimini.com
DNS record(s):
hotelbeverlyrimini.com. SPF (no records)
hotelbeverlyrimini.com. 21600 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:95.254.117.90 ip4:62.149.140.224 ip4:62.149.140.218 ip4:77.232.76.11 ip4:77.232.76.12 ip4:77.232.66.250 a:smtp1.servage.net -all"

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result: neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: